# Getting syntax error

Tags: mysql

I am getting syntax error in following statement...but I want to use it by USING STATEMENT.

> SELECT
>   user_job.level1,user_job.tab_level,job.money_gain,job.exp_gain,job.energy_required,job.name,job_tem.no
>   LEFT JOIN job USING(job_id) AND LEFT
>   JOIN job_item USING(job_id)
>
> job_id is common in all the tables.

Comment: can you split the query on multiple lines, run it again and post the syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're missing the `FROM` in the statement, so mysql knows from which table you're selecting. I'm assuming you're selecting from user_job table since this table is mentioned first in your select statement.

Second there must be no `AND` between multiple joins.

So you're complete and correct SQL statement should look like this:

```
SELECT
  user_job.level1,
  user_job.tab_level,
  job.money_gain,
  job.exp_gain,
  job.energy_required,
  job.name,
  job_tem.no
FROM user_job
LEFT JOIN job USING(job_id)
LEFT JOIN job_item USING(job_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the FROM-clause and as other have pointed out, you don't chain Joins with ANDs.

Comment: this is not an answer it should be comment

Comment: How is it not a valid answer to this question?

Comment: because it's a question itself, and it doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: So missing the from clause doesn't cause syntax errors? Anyways I'll change it to be an answer.

Comment: it does cause on error, but he would have still gotten a syntax error after adding the `FROM`, because - like you've written now - there was an `AND` too much.

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly missing `FROM`. The query could look like this.

```
SELECT user_job.level1,
  user_job.tab_level,
  job.money_gain,
  job.exp_gain,
  job.energy_required,
  job.name,
  job_tem.no 
FROM job 
  LEFT JOIN user_job USING(job_id)
  LEFT JOIN job_item USING(job_id)
```

Comment: Same answer as Daj pan Spokoj